# What is the best survey or analysis of products or services in demand in an economy at the moment?

Tags: markets, labour

Is there a thinktank, survey or publication that is considered a gold standard in analyzing what jobs, skills, services, commodities, or resources are or would be most in demand in a given economy, large or small, at the present?

For example, perhaps using a survey, or some other analytical techniques, such as seeing what jobs people do on a country’s tax returns, or what job positions are advertised the most on large job sites like Indeed, or a more subjective analysis, they could publish a report yearly saying something like, “In Sweden, the professions with the highest demand due to low supply are doctors, engineers and software developers. The fastest growing entry level job is a food courier, for example Wolt or Uber Eats. The job with declining demand are travel agents. Due to global events, there is high demand for energy in Sweden. There is high demand for learning English, but also high supply, and many years of education to enter the field, so it’s not the strongest economic avenue.”

Or something like this?